# Performance Monitor by Process Id?

Tags: performance-monitor

when you have serveral processes with the same name how do you differenciate between them in Performance Monintor.

It uses Name,Name#1, Name#2, Name#3 etc to identify the instances.

Is there any logic to the #n ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question: No, you cannot differentiate them.